# Обход лока БД firefox

Tags: javascript, linux, sqlite, firefox

Имеется js код, который по нажатию кнопок на сайте создает куки с некоторым содержимым. Так же есть bash скрипт который читает эти куки и выполняет команды в терминале в соответствии с содержимым, однако, вся эта система перестала работать на последних версиях Firefox'а, т.к. теперь `cookies.sqlite` получает `lock` при запущенном браузере.

Сидеть на старых версиях Firefox не вариант, некоторые сайты перестали корректно работать на них.

Есть ли возможность обойти Lock? Может есть другие варианты передачи информации на компьютер клиента и считывания этой информации в терминал?